# Basic rigidbody movement

Tags: unity, c#, physics

This is a noob question but, what is the rigidbody movement equivalent of:

```
transform.position += transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's:

```
Vector3 newPosition  = transform.position 
                     + transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;

rigidbody.MovePosition(newPosition);
```

or

```
rigidbody.velocity = transform.right * speed;
```

Comment: Shouldn't I be using Time.fixedDeltaTime instead of Time.deltaTime?

Comment: If you're doing this in FixedUpdate, deltaTime returns fixedDeltaTime automatically. If you're not doing this in FixedUpdate, then you want to be using the actual timestep of your frame, which is deltaTime. So in both cases, deltaTime is what you want. It's rare that you should need to access fixedDeltaTime manually.

Comment: Ok. Thank you!!